# Find separated lines in a 2D coordinate system

Tags: c#, algorithm, swift, coordinates, graph-algorithm

I'm currently looking for a good algorithm to find separated line in 2D coordinate.

Here is a representation of what I have :

[image: lines]

So here the algorithm should return that I have 3 differents separated lines and I would like then to be able later during the execution to know to which line a point belong.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this ?

Note : The area and the lines are represented in memory by a 2D array of boolean. Color are note part of the data.

Comment: These don't appear to be "lines" ,They're just disconnected areas. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Comment: Yes that's correct. It may happen that we get something different that a line if there consecutive true value on multiple row and column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example I come up with: (tested in a Playground with Swift 2 Xcode 7 beta 2)

```
struct Point{
    var x, y: Int

    init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }

    /**
    get points around it (Xs around P)
    if all {
        XXX
        XPX
        XXX
    } else {
        OXO
        XPX
        OXO
    }
    **/
    func pointsAround(all all: Bool = true) -> [Point] {
        if all {
            return Array(-1...1).flatMap{ x in
                (-1...1).flatMap{ y in
                    if x == 0 && y == 0 {
                        return nil
                    }
                    return Point(self.x + x, self.y + y)
                }
            }
        }
        return Array(-1...1).flatMap{ x in
            (-1...1).flatMap{ y in
                if abs(x) == abs(y) {
                    return nil
                }
                return Point(self.x + x, self.y + y)
            }
        }
    }
}

func distinguishAreas(var array: [[Bool]]) -> [[Point]] {
    // result
    var points = [[Point]]()

    let width = array.count
    let height = array[0].count
    // returns array[x][y] but with savety check (otherwise false)
    func getBool(x: Int, _ y: Int) -> Bool {
        guard 0..<width ~= x && 0..<height ~= y else { return false }
        return array[x][y]
    }

    // points where to check array
    var crawlers = [Point]()

    // loop through whole array
    for x in 0..<array.count {
        for y in 0..<array[0].count where array[x][y] {
            // if point (array[x][x]) is true

            // new point where to check
            crawlers = [Point(x, y)]

            // points to append (one area)
            var newPoints = [Point]()
            // loop as long as area is not "eaten" by crawlers
            while crawlers.count != 0 {

                // crawlers "eat" area and remove some of themselves
                crawlers = crawlers.filter{
                    let temp = array[$0.x][$0.y]
                    array[$0.x][$0.y] = false
                    return temp
                }

                newPoints += crawlers

                // make new crawlers around old crawlers and only where area is
                // passing false to p.pointsAround is mouch faster than true
                crawlers = crawlers.flatMap{ p in
                    p.pointsAround(all: false).filter{ getBool($0.x, $0.y) }
                }
            }
            points.append(newPoints)
        }
    }
    return points
}
```

**EDIT:** made a change under the comment `// crawlers "eat" area and remove some of themselves` which makes the algorithm more efficient with big areas

Comment: great solution Qbyte, thanks a lot. Moreover it's in swift 2. Even if I still don't use it it's really interesting! There is really interesting new features in this version!

Comment: Should I convert it to Swift 1.2 Syntax ?

Comment: Ah no don't worry that's fine^^ I didn't switch to swift 2.0 because it's in beta but I know about the new syntax. Anyway thanks again for your solution.

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: Ah yes, I will accept it soon. But It's just that in my case I don't have exactly a bool array and I can't change the array value when crawler "eat " them instead. I want to use a visited array instead and moreover invert the logic (use false value to draw lines). Right know, maybe because of that, I have a infinite loop. I wanted to solve this before to accept it.

Comment: At least in Swift, if you pass an array it gets copied due to it's value semantics so you can modify it as you want (mostly) without side effects.

Comment: Ok, Qbyte, your algorithm is great anyway there is an error when you have consecutive similar bit at the beginning. I had to use a set instead of an array to avoid duplicate point inside the crawler. So also I change Point to implement Hashable. Can you fix that and I will mark your answer as accepted:)

Comment: Ok I think it can be the accepted answer. Anyway don't you thing you need to put newPoints += crawlers after you filter crawlers to avoid points duplication?

Answer (score 2):

What you need seems to be connected components of a graph, where each cell is a vertex and vertices are connected if they share a side. There are several algorithms for finding the connected components, most notably the breadth-first search and depth-first search.

Each of these algorithm can return the number of components ("lines") and also allow for each cell to be assigned the number of component it belongs to.

Comment: Thanks Petr, I will get a look to those algoritms